# Convergence of $\hat \beta_N - \hat \beta_{N-1}$ where $\hat \beta_N$ is the least squares solution of $Y_N = X_N\beta_N + \varepsilon_N$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics, regression, data-analysis

Suppose we are given a set of random observations $\{y_i,x_{i1},\dots,x_{ip}\}_{i=1}^N$. Based on these observations, we can form the multiple linear regression model in matrix form
$$
Y_N = X_N\beta + \varepsilon_N,
$$
where the error, conditioned on $X$, is normally distributed with mean zero and finite variance. I have used the subscript $N$ to explicitly indicate that we have used $N$ observations.

When we solve this model with least squares we find the estimated regression coefficient vector $\hat \beta_N$. We could also leave out the last observation and solve the model
$$
Y_{N-1} = X_{N-1}\beta + \varepsilon_{N-1},
$$
to find the estimated regression coefficients $\hat \beta_{N-1}$.

The explicit expression for the estimated regression coefficients is well-known. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\hat \beta_N &= \beta_N + (X_N^TX_N)^{-1}X^T \varepsilon_N, \\
\hat \beta_{N-1} &= \beta_{N-1} + (X_{N-1}^TX_{N-1})^{-1}X^T \varepsilon_{N-1}.
\end{align}
$$
As $N$ gets large intuitively it seems there will be negligible difference between the estmiated regression coefficients $\hat \beta_N$ ad $\hat \beta_{N-1}$. But can we quantify this precisely? Is it possible to show that $E(N) := \hat \beta_N - \hat \beta_{N-1}$ converges to zero in probability or almost surely as $N \to 0$? And in particular, how fast it converges to zero?

Comment: I will comment also on the convergence in $L^p$ (your question on mathoverflow), if you edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From the discussion on MO) I guess that the subscript $N$ in $\beta_N$ is a lapse.

It is well know that, conditionally on $X_N$, $\hat \beta_N$ is unbiased and $\mathrm{Cov}(\hat \beta_N) = \sigma^2 \big(X_N^T X_N\big)^{-1}$.

Now in order to have some convergence, one naturally needs additional (to the usual Gauss–Markov) assumptions. Say, if $x_i$ are iid and square integrable, then
$$
X_N^T X_N = \sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|^2 \sim n\,\mathrm{E}[|x_1|^2], n\to\infty,
$$
almost surely. As a result, $\hat \beta_n \overset{\mathrm P}\longrightarrow \beta$, $n\to\infty$, moreover, $\sqrt{n} |\hat\beta_n - \beta|$ is bounded in probability. (So the convergence rate is loosely $1/\sqrt{n}$.)

Comment: Thanks for addressing this question. My central issue at the moment is explained in the comments of my [latest post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500795/e-beta-n-beta2-mathbfx-sigma2-mathbfxt-mathbfx-1-what-ab) on stats.stackstackexhange. Essentially I need to know the order of magnitude of the moments $E[(\hat \beta - \beta)^k]$ for $k \ge 3$, as $n \to \infty$ because I am doing a second order Taylor expansion and I want to be sure it is safe to drop the third and higher order terms.

Comment: It would be great if you could take a look at the stats.se post it if you get a chance, I cannot find anything in the literature that provides the order of magnitude of these moments.

Comment: I'll have a look.